# Changing the model

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

Imagine a simple UserControl with one TextBox (CustomerName), and two buttons (Save/Cancel).

This UserControl sits within a parent control with two more buttons (PreviousCustomer/NextCustomer)

The problem is I don't know where to pass in the model to the presenter. Do I go through the view constructor? What if the model changes (PreviousCustomer/NextCustomer is clicked)? Do I create a new view every time? This seems wasteful if the UserControl is complex with many children. Could I implement an UpdateModel method in the view and presenter, or would that be incorrect?

Here's my code:

```
public interface IModel
{
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class Presenter
{
    private IView _view;
    private IModel _model;

    public Presenter(IView view, IModel model)
    {
        _view = view;
        _model = model;
        _view.CustomerName = _model.CustomerName;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _model.CustomerName = _view.CustomerName;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _view.CustomerName = _model.CustomerName;
    }

    public void UpdateModel(IModel newModel)
    {
        _model = newModel;
        _view.CustomerName = _model.CustomerName;
    }
}

public interface IView
{
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class View : UserControl, IView
{
    private Presenter _presenter;

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get { return CustomerNameEditBox.Text; }
        set { CustomerNameEditBox.Text = value; }
    }

    //Is this the right place to pass in the model?
    public View(IModel model)
    {
        _presenter = new Presenter(this, model);
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _presenter.Save();
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _presenter.Cancel();
    }

    public void UpdateModel(IModel newModel)
    {
        _presenter.UpdateModel(newModel);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As stated in the comments below, I think it is best to have the view to be completely dumb and know nothing of the presenter or model. Here is my revised code.

Model:

```
public interface IModel
{
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class Model : IModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public Model(string name)
    {
        CustomerName = name;
    }
}
```

View:

```
public interface IView
{
    event EventHandler SaveClick;
    event EventHandler CancelClick;
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class View : UserControl, IView
{
    public event EventHandler SaveClick
    {
        add { SaveButton.Click += value; }
        remove { SaveButton.Click -= value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler CancelClick
    {
        add { CancelButton.Click += value; }
        remove { CancelButton.Click -= value; }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get { return CustomerNameEditBox.Text; }
        set { CustomerNameEditBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class Presenter
{
    private IView _view;
    private IModel _model;

    public Control View
    {
        get { return (Control)_view; } 
    }

    public Presenter(IView view, IModel model)
    {
        _view = view;
        _view.SaveClick += new EventHandler(_view_SaveClick);
        _view.CancelClick += new EventHandler(_view_CancelClick);
        _model = model;
        _view.CustomerName = _model.CustomerName;
    }

    void _view_SaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _model.CustomerName = _view.CustomerName;
    }

    void _view_CancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _view.CustomerName = _model.CustomerName;
    }

    public void ChangeModel(IModel newModel)
    {
        _model = newModel;
        _view.CustomerName = _model.CustomerName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MainProgram : Form
{
    public void ArbitraryMethod()
    {
        //Create a new model object
        IModel model1 = new Model("test1");

        //Create the presenter with the model and any view implementing IView
        Presenter presenter = new Presenter(new View(), model1);

        //Add the view to a panel control in this form
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(presenter.View);

        //Change the model
        IModel model2 = new Model("test2");
        presenter.ChangeModel(model2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Who invokes Save and Cancel methods? Is it view?

Comment: Yes, view has SaveButton_Click/CancelButton_Click methods which call the Save/Cancel methods in the presenter.

Answer (score 0):

If your design is MVP (Model View Presenter) you should create your model inside the presenter. That's the idea behind this pattern. 
The view communicates with the presenter and the presenter offers him all the methods, properties, events he needed. 
In your example you decided to create a model as well. You can do that, but please hide it from the view. 
Related to your example, remove the IModel parameter in the constructor and create a new one in the code instead.

Consider setting the View changes via methods (_view.SetName("me"). That could make your life easier later.

There's no need to create a new winforms form. Perhaps, I don't understand your point here..

Update:

Take a look at the example below. You have interfaces for view, presenter and model ( based from your code). I just renamed IModel to ICustomer to make my point clear. The presenter creates a model for doing some I/O stuff and gets a view interface for updating the windows or whatever is behind the interface.

```
public interface IView
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomer
{
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public interface IModel
{
    void Save(ICustomer entity);
    void Update(ICustomer entity);
    ICustomer Create();
}


public class Customer : ICustomer
{
    public string CustomerName {get;set;}

}

public class MyModel : IModel
{

    public void Save(ICustomer entity)
    {
        //Do something here..
    }

    public void Update(ICustomer entity)
    {
        //Do something here..
    }

    public ICustomer Create()
    {
        return new Customer();
    }
}

public class Presenter
{
    private IView _view;
    private ICustomer _entity;
    private IModel _model = new MyModel();

    public Presenter(IView view)
    {
        _view = view;
        _model = new MyModel();
        _entity = _model.Create();

        _view.CustomerName = _entity.CustomerName;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _model.Save(_entity);
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _entity = _model.Create();
    }

    public void UpdateModel(ICustomer customer)
    {
        _model.Update(customer);
        _view.CustomerName = customer.CustomerName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how the model can be created within the presenter. Say the model is a Customer object that is retrieved from a Customers table in a database. How does the presenter know which Customer to retrieve. All it is aware of is the view that instantiated it.

Comment: In this case the presenter must inform the view about the new customer. I understand your point now. Your IModel interface is the Model and not class that handles the model instances. But back to your example. The view can ask your presenter that he wants to show the customer x. The presenter then invokes any database and updates the view (i.e. via method).  You should rename your IModel to ICustomer that makes it easier to follow you.

Comment: Ok, say IModel does define the class that handles customer instances. It still wouldn't be possible to create the model inside the presenter. How would this enable state information like current customer? Also, I thought one of the advantages to MVP was that the model was passed into the presenter as an interface, therefore any Model conforming to IModel would be compatible.

Comment: I added some code to demonstrate my point. I would rename your IModel to an IEntity or ICustomer class and delegate the work to model object.

Comment: I really appreciate the help Bjoern, but I still don't like the way the model is created in the presenter. In doing this, there is no need for IModel, as the _model member is always instantiated as a MyModel. I think the presenter should be supplied with both the IView and IModel externally like in the "Encapsulated View Style" and "Observing Presenter Style" described here: http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2008/11/23/model-view-presenter-styles/

Comment: It's ok, we're just discussung. I see that my approach is also mentioned in your link. You can create a Presenter() with the default constructor and the presenter creates a Model on it's own.  But use the other one if it's more useful for you.